# Export data from HTML5 local storage is not working on Phonegap

Tags: html, local-storage, export-to-excel, phonegap-build

I'm trying to export data from HTML5 localStorage by using compile service from [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com). Export   function is working fine on PC but not when compiled into mobile app. When export button is clicked nothing happen. It should download the file to mobile device. Other functions such as save, edit and delete are working fine both PC and mobile.

Any suggestion?

I have been trying both `data:application/csv;charset=utf-8` 
and example from [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File). None of them are working.